# Change File with extension txt to json in C#

Tags: c#, json, file, txt, formatted

I have problem with serialized a File this one below to **json** format.
I would like to make a json file from the file .txt I have attached at the bottom with a helpful serialization. And I need sugestions what exacly I should do to change this file to json format but reading data from a file not included them in code.

.txt --> .json

```
namespace zadanko
{
  class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {

    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter path name of file: ");
    var fileName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File dosen't exist");
        return;
    }


    FileStream filestream = new FileStream(fileName + "_formatted.json", FileMode.Create);
    var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);


    streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
    Console.SetError(streamwriter);

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    string jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();

    String serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sr );

    //write all books automatic
    Console.WriteLine(serialized);
    }
  }
 }

 public class Book
{
  public string category { get; set; }
  public string author { get; set; }
  public string title { get; set; }
  public double price { get; set; }
  public string isbn { get; set; }
 }

public class Bicycle
 {
    public string color { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
 }

  public class Store
{
     public List<Book> book { get; set; }
    public Bicycle bicycle { get; set; }
 }

   public class Root
  {
  public Store store { get; set; }
  }
```

````
Text:

```text
BOOKS:
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 | category  | author           | title                  | price | isbn          |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 | reference | Nigel Rees       | Sayings of the Century | 8,95  |               |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 | fiction   | Evelyn Waugh     | Sword of Honour        | 12,99 |               |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 | fiction   | J. R. R. Tolkien | The Lord of the Rings  | 22,99 | 0-395-19395-8 |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 | fiction   | Evelyn Waugh     | Sword of Honour        | 12,99 |               |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 Count: 4

BICYCLE:
 ----------------- 
 | color | price |
 ----------------- 
 | red   | 19,95 |
 ----------------- 

 Count: 1
````

Comment: Please clarify your question - "I have problem" doesn't tell us anything about what you're expecting vs what you actually see.

Comment: Yes, for example, the content of the output file, and what it is expected to be would be nice.

Comment: I need change file txt this one which i posted to format json in new created file.

Comment: If the text file contains literally the output you've shown at the bottom of your question then you first need to figure out the right way to read that into .NET objects, the JSON serialization is trivial after that. There is nothing, however, that will do that kind of conversion for you automatically, you will have to write the code that reads that text and understands its format and constructs objects from it.

Comment: If, however, your problem is just that you have a file with a .txt extension and you need this file to have a .json extension, with the exact same content, so it's just a filename change, then use `File.Move`.